# Ionic 2 - RC2.0, plugin for uploading file (transfer) wont’t work

Tags: php, android, cordova, ionic2

The past 2 days I've spend struggling to make my app  to upload the image taken with phone's camera on a PHP server. The code on the server works just fine but  the `$_FILES` var is empty.

My problem is similar with the one described here, also without a solution [Corodova file transfer not working after updating to ionic 2 RC0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40046639/corodova-file-transfer-not-working-after-updating-to-ionic-2-rc0).

My app connects to the camera, takes the picture, loads it and sends  it to the server. The process takes a few seconds and that it. I revive no error on upload and yet the `$_FILES[""]` is empty.

I have tried several methods, including using headers and removing  headers but nothing worked. And the same problem every time: no file uploaded on the server.

Technologies:

- Cordova CLI: 6.1.1
- Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.2
- Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.4
- Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.2
- Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.44
- OS: Windows 7 SP1
- Node Version: v6.2.0

My Code:

Imports:

```
import { Camera } from 'ionic-native';
import { Transfer } from 'ionic-native';
```

camera.html:

```
<button ion-button color="dark" (click)="takePhoto()">Open camera </button>
<img [src]="imageURL" *ngIf="imageURL" />
<br>imageURL={{imageURL}}
<br><button ion-button color="dark" (click)="upload1()">Upload image</button>
```

camera.ts:

```
takePhoto(){
    Camera.getPicture().then((imageData) => {
       this.imageURL = imageData;
    }, (err) => {
       console.log(err);
    });
}

upload1(){
    const ft = new Transfer();
    var options = {
         fileKey: 'file',
         fileName: 'file_name',
         headers: {
             'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
         }
    }
    ft.upload(this.imageURL,encodeURI("https://www.myserver.ro/my_file.php?op=upload"),options)

    .then((data) => {
        // success
        alert("OK:"+this.imageURL);
        }, (err) => {
            // error
            alert("ERROR ON UPLOAD: "+err.toString()+"\n picture url: "+this.imageURL);  
        })
}
```

Thanks a lot.